# How to flatten pandas series of series?

Tags: python, pandas

When using dataframe/series string extract method, the result is a `series` of `series`. How can I flatten this and remove the internal series objects without iterating the rows?

```
df = DataFrame({"a": ["asf cat llma 3X dog elepnt", "cat dog child monkey 5X sljka", "fsdjkl; dsfaa"]})
sr = df[df.a.str.contains("[3-6]X", na=False)].a.str.extract("([3-6]X)")

# sr is a series of series
[type(sr.iloc[i]) for i in range(sr.shape[0])]
# --> [<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>]

# I can add the expand parameter to no effect
sr = df[df.a.str.contains("[3-6]X", na=False)].a.str.extract("([3-6]X)", expand=True)
[type(sr.iloc[i]) for i in range(sr.shape[0])]
# --> [<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>]
```

Comment: `df[df.a.str.contains("[3-6]X", na=False)].a.str.extract("([3-6]X)", expand=False)` ? returns a single series of strings.

Comment: `sr[0]` will also help

Comment: @ScottBoston i copied and pasted directly from the interpreter, so for me it does not.

Comment: @johnrobot doesnt `sr[0]` work for you?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC,

```
sr = df[df.a.str.contains("[3-6]X", na=False)].a.str.extract("([3-6]X)", expand=False)

[type(sr.iloc[i]) for i in range(sr.shape[0])]
```

Output:

```
[str, str]
```

Comment: I copied and pasted directly from the interpreter, so for me this is not the output i get hence the question... maybe there is a difference between pandas versions. I'm on an enterprise system and must use pandas 2.1
the solution that works for me is: `sr.iloc[:, 0]`

Comment: @johnrobot Maybe you're missing a detail here: In your question you have `expand=True`, which is already the default. This answer uses `expand=False`, which returns the same as `sr.iloc[:, 0]`.

Comment: @e-motta yep totally missed that, `expand=False` gives me a series of strings.